# How do I modify this code to write to a file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, permutation, filewriter, printwriter

I am attempting to modify this Heap's Algorithm that shows all possible permutations of an input of strings.  I am trying to modify the code to be able to be used with the Scanner class with a writer file.  When I try to write to a new file, it does not add all 24 strings as it should, but rather adds the first 4.  Because it is a void method, I cannot use pw.println(obj.heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length)). Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Thanks

P.S. I found this code online, and I acknowledge that it is not mine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class HeapAlgo 
{ 




    void heapPermutation(String a[], int size, int n) throws IOException
    { 
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("note.txt");
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


 // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained 
 // permutation 
       if (size == 1) 
          for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
          { 
              System.out.println(a[i] + "");



          } 


          for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
          { 
             heapPermutation(a, size-1, n); 

// if size is odd, swap first and last 
// element 
                if (size % 2 == 1) 
                { 
                    String temp = a[0]; 
                    a[0] = a[size-1]; 
                    a[size-1] = temp; 
                } 

// If size is even, swap ith and last 
// element 
                else
                { 
                   String temp = a[i]; 
                   a[i] = a[size-1]; 
                   a[size-1] = temp; 
                } 


         }


  } 


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{ 

   HeapAlgo obj = new HeapAlgo(); 
   String a[] = new String["abcd","bbbb","cccc","dddd"];
   obj.heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PrintWriter` is initilized inside the heapPermutation method, which because it's called recursively `heapPermutation(a, size-1, n)` will be overridden each time. I believe the default behaviour for this is to replace the file, not append to it.

You should create a constructor to initialize the `PrintWriter` so it is not reinitilized each time.

```
class HeapAlgo {
    // create a writer at the class level
    private PrintWriter _pw;

    // Create a constructor to assign the writer
    public HeapAlgo(PrintWriter pw) {
       this._pw = pw;
    }

    void heapPermutation(String a[], int size, int n) throws IOException { 
    // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained 
    // permutation 
        if (size == 1) 
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
                System.out.println(a[i] + "");
                this._pw.print(a[i] + ""); // print here I belive?
            }

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { 
            heapPermutation(a, size-1, n); 

            // if size is odd, swap first and last 
            // element 
            if (size % 2 == 1) { 
                String temp = a[0]; 
                a[0] = a[size-1]; 
                a[size-1] = temp; 
            }

            // If size is even, swap ith and last 
            // element 
            else { 
               String temp = a[i]; 
               a[i] = a[size-1]; 
               a[size-1] = temp; 
            } 
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("note.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    HeapAlgo obj = new HeapAlgo(pw); // Pass in a writer
    String a[] = new String["abcd","bbbb","cccc","dddd"];
    obj.heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length);
```